spresense SDKの makeコマンドとspresense IDEの「アプリケーションのビルド」の違い
spresense IDEを使用して開発し始めたのですが、makeコマンドとツリーを右クリックし「アプリケーションのビルド」の違いについて教えてください。
経緯：myProjectにアプリ(my_app)を追加し、ビルドをして動作確認していましたが、makeコマンドでビルドした場合と「アプリケーションのビルド」で結果が異なる。
makeコマンド時：
・my_appがビルドされない。
・実行時のBuiltin Apps:nsh, sh
「アプリケーションのビルド」時：
・my_appがビルドされる。
・実行時のBuiltin Apps:nsh, sh, my_app
構成
-spresense
->SDK
-myProject
->my_app
そもそもビルド対象が異なるのではと思っているのですが、範囲や対象がどのように違うのか知りたいです。
初歩的ですみませんがご教授ください。
不足情報があれば教えてください。
追記：2024/08/06
環境：・windows11
・WSL2環境
・Spresense VSCode IDE：1.5.100
・spresense-sdk：v3.2.0
make時のメッセージ:
Create version.h
LN: platform/board to /home/user/spresense/sdk/apps/platform/dummy
Register: nsh
Register: sh
CPP:  /home/user/spresense/nuttx/boards/arm/cxd56xx/spresense/scripts/ramconfig-new.ld-> /home/user/spresense/nuttx/boards/arm/cxd56xx/spresense/scriptLD: nuttx
Generating: nuttx.spk
tools/cxd56/mkspk -c2 nuttx nuttx nuttx.spk;
File nuttx.spk is successfully created.
Done.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/spresense/nuttx'

「アプリケーションのビルド」時のメッセージ:
Create version.h
LN: platform/board to /home/user/spresense/sdk/apps/platform/dummy
Register: my_app
Register: nsh
Register: sh
CPP:  /home/user/spresense/nuttx/boards/arm/cxd56xx/spresense/scripts/ramconfig-new.ld-> /home/user/spresense/nuttx/boards/arm/cxd56xx/sLD: nuttx
Generating: nuttx.spk
tools/cxd56/mkspk -c2 nuttx nuttx nuttx.spk;
File nuttx.spk is successfully created.
Done.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/spresense/nuttx'


make コマンドを実行した際、「ビルドされない」だけではなく、何かメッセージ等は表示されていませんか？また、念のため実行環境に関する情報 (OS の種類等) も記載があると回答が付きやすいと思います。

コメントありがとうございます。使用環境とビルド時のメッセージを追加いたしました。特にエラーや警告などは出ていないと思います。

IDE（VSCode）で、configの選択を行うとプロジェクトの管理場にsdk.configが作成されて、ビルド時にはそちらが参照されているようです。それはCLI上のmakeでの.configとは異なるものになっているので、単純に共有化はされていないようです。

返信が遅れ申し訳ないです。
いろいろ試してみて薄々思い始めていましたがやはりそうなんですね。回答ありがとうございます。助かりました。
